# Order SQL data by IN (0,1,2) set

Tags: sql

I  am facing some difficulties in sql query

```
select * from country order by 
case when country_id in(254,43,253,91,82,175) then 0  else country.country_id  end
ASC
```

I want the record thet will be given fist case condition be order in the way they are given in the query like ...

```
254
43
253
91
82
175
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use MySQL, I believe this is the query you want.

```
SELECT * 
FROM country  
ORDER BY FIELD(country_id, 175, 82, 91, 253, 43, 254) DESC  -- reverse order here
       , country_id ;
```

or this (for any SQL product):

```
SELECT * 
FROM country  
ORDER BY CASE country_id
           WHEN 254 THEN 1
           WHEN  43 THEN 2
           WHEN 253 THEN 3
           WHEN  91 THEN 4
           WHEN  82 THEN 5
           WHEN 175 THEN 6
               ELSE 7
         END 
       , country_id ;
```

Comment: Hello ryan.Thanks for the reply but what i need is to show all other records which is in data base and those records should be in the top as they are given in the array..

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I don't know of anyway in SQL to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.Finally i got it.

Comment: Thank you @ypercube for your edits, seems I got some undeserved rep for this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's solution if you want conformance to [`core SQL-99 standard`](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser99/index.tml):

```
SELECT *
FROM country
ORDER BY
 CASE 
      WHEN country_id IN (254,43,253,91,82,175) THEN 1
      ELSE 666
 END, country_id
```